# Bypass for the certificate must be valid for 825 days or fewer

Tags: macos, certificate, ssl

Is there a way to workaround issue with certs valid for long time (10 years)?
I work in a corporation where Macs are not common and we have some internal long live certificates.

I know I can add single cert to trusted but any option to make Mac to trust all internal certs?

Comment: This only takes effect for certs issued after Sept 1, 2020 and for [root CA's preinstalled with Apple's OS's](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210770).  Are you referring to one of those?

Comment: I believe it affects all certificates issued after March 1, 2018

Comment: You might want to investigate that further.  I'm not an expert in this area but my [limited research shows it's only certain certs](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2020/03/06/apple-making-changes-to-maximum-lifetime-limits-for-ssl-certificates-as-of-september-2020/) (which is why I'm not making this an answer).

Comment: So when I try to open one of the internal sites with safari there is a general cert invalid error, but on chrome I get NET::ERR_CERT_VALIDITY_TOO_LONG
When i open cert i see chain with root ca which is marked as trusted but site cert is not trusted

Comment: Is it one of the Apple certs I indicated in my first comment?

Comment: No it's internal cert signed with internal root ca

Comment: Your IT department should stand up its own internal CA sever for internal use and use that to issue certs that comply with the new standard. [All major players have signed on](https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/maximum-ssltls-certificate-validity-now-one-year); Apple, Microsoft, Google, Mozilla etc. will deliver browsers that comply with the 13 month limit. 10 years is way too long (IMHO) and modifying a CA server to comply is relatively easy.

Answer (score 2):

A quick workaround of you are using [Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/16648034?hl=en&msgid=17568038) is to use the bypass word "thisisunsafe":

1. Go to the (trusted) page
2. Once you get to the message that says "Your connection is not private" click anywhere on the page
3. Type: thisisunsafe

This will add your page to a whitelist of the browser and instantly bypass the warning. Don't do this on sites you don't trust.

Comment: I think this only works for Chrome, not Safari

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted.  It's a workaround and the OP didn't specify a browser, so this answer is valid. +1 and Welcome to Ask Different.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to workaround issue with certs valid for long time (10 years)?

There's no client side workaround to simply ignore or bypass invalid certificates.  You have 3 options:

- import the certificate manually into Keychain Access and/or your browsers
- batch import the certificates provided by your IT department
- IT should stand up their own CA server that complies with the new standard of 13 month validity.

#### Further Reading

- [Setting Up Certificate Authorities (CAs) in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/setting-certificate-authorities-firefox)
- [Add certificates to a keychain using Keychain Access on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/add-certificates-to-a-keychain-kyca2431/mac)
- [Import and export keychain items using Keychain Access on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/import-and-export-keychain-items-kyca35961/10.5/mac/10.15)
- [Set up TLS (or SSL) inspection on Chrome devices](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3505249?hl=en)

#### Summary

Basically, to avoid having to accept each individual certificate, your IT department will need to supply you with your applicable certificates for the internal sites, servers, and everything else you need to connect to so that you can add them to your browsers and/or key chain.  It would be less intrusive if they stood up their own CA server, but if they have self signed certs for all of the internal services, they would need to distribute them to everyone so they could be added in one single go.

Comment: Indeed - an MDM assists this injection of “to be trusted” certificates and depending on how elaborate your needs you would just push a master certificate that unlocks all the enterprise certificates that don’t meet Apple’s default security controls. This bypasses the risk, but in a controlled and reportable / manageable process.